# using vue-videobg with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use this package here, https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-videobg to create a video background for my homepage.

the video background component looks likes this

```
<template>
    <videoBg :source="'https://youtu.be/x3bfa3DZ8JM'"></videoBg>
</template>

<script>
import VideoBg from 'vue-videobg'
export default {
  components: {
    VideoBg
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

when importing this component into other component I get syntax error. unexpected token< error 
and most of the error files say missing stack frames. The import line is the when this error appears.

Does anyone know why this is? Did i register the package in my project correctly?

thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post a gist or a codesandbox link ?

Comment: Hi Loki, I imitated the error in codesandbox. Please have a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-5wifp?fontsize=14

Comment: Hmm seems to be issue with library: https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-videobg/issues/15

Comment: Please note that this error only happens when i completely reload into the page with the component imported. If i load the other page first e.g. about and use the navbar to go to the homepage(where the component is) it loads fine. I can't imitate this on codesandbox for some reason.

Comment: @Tanpo I created a similar package to that but it was inspired by teslas background video. Have a look https://github.com/avidofood/vue-responsive-video-background-player Maybe it works for next

Comment: @Shadrix. Thank you for sharing! looks good. I've already written my own component for this. Kinda works the same way as yours :)